# css divs align in Chrome (18) and Firefox (11) but not in Safari (5.1). cannot figure out why

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, html, safari

In Firefox and Chrome, the "filters_area" div is correctly left-aligned under the "tabs" div, aligned to the left side of the browser window.  In Safari however the "filters_area" div is left-aligned to the right-edge of the "tabs" div.  Any ideas why this div is aligned differently in Safari?  Here's the code;

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<ul id="tab_list" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
<span id="Items">Items</span>
</li>
<span id="tab_options">
<span id="help_link" href="#help">help</span>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<span id="myaccount">settings</span>
&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="logout">log out</a>
</span>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="instructions_area">
<input id="search_box" type="text" value="Search..." name="search">
<div id="filters_area">
<span id="Everything" class="filter active_filter">On Hand</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tabs {
border      : 0px;
height      : 34px;
}

#tab_list {
border      : 0px;
display     : block;
}

#instructions_area  {
background  : #FFF url( '../images/products_top.png' ) repeat-x ;
height      : 40px;
line-height : 32px;
padding-left: 10px;
}

#filters_area {
color       : #555;
height      : 40px;
font-size   : 14px;
float       : left;
line-height : 32px;
}

#search_box {
border      : 1px solid #AAEE22;
color       : #390;
height      : 18px;
float       : right;
font-size   : 12px;
font-weight : bold;
margin      : 4px 10px 0px 0px;
width       : 175px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help much without the corresponding CSS. Could you make a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have included the JavaScript code here as well.. I ultimately went through the site using Firebug for Firefox and deselected certain attributes of every element on the page until I noticed one that affected the alignment of the filters_area section in Safari.  Turns out that the ul id "tab_list" was picking up 0.2em of padding from a jquery file.  This caused Safari to force the filters_area out of alignment but was not a problem for IE, Chrome or Firefox.  I removed the 0.2 em padding and Safari works fine.  Appreciate all the suggested fixes.  They helped shed light on the most viable path toward resolution.